# Prove this inequality (similar to Hoeffding's inequality)

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Consider a sequence of independent variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with mean 0 and $|X_i| \leq c$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$ Prove that:

$$P\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq n\varepsilon \Big) \leq \exp\left( -\frac{(1/2) n\varepsilon^2}{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] + \frac{c\varepsilon}{3}}\right)$$

I am trying to take a similar approach to the proof of Hoeffding's inequality, but I am not sure why there is an extra $\frac{c\varepsilon}{3}$ term in the denominator? Does someone mind explaining?

Comment: ok, Now I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_i = X_i/c, \forall i$. 
Then $Y_i \le 1$, $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2] = \frac{1}{c^2}\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]$, 
for $i = 1, 2, \cdots$.

From Theorem 3 in [1], we have, for any $\epsilon' > 0$, 
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i > n\epsilon'\Big)
\le \mathrm{exp}\Big(- \frac{n\epsilon'^2}{2(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2] + \frac{\epsilon'}{3})}\Big)$$
which results in
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > n\epsilon\Big)
\le \mathrm{exp}\Big(- \frac{\frac{n}{2}\epsilon^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] + \frac{c\epsilon}{3}}\Big)$$
where $\epsilon = c\epsilon'$. We are done.

[1] Boucheron, Lugosi, and Bousquet, "Concentration Inequalities".
http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_conc.pdf